# Cannot Compile and add GDAL library for Visual C++ project in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: gdal, c++, c

I wanted o create a project using the GDAL library and its API for C code.
I can create an executable for this code by entering the following on the command line in a Linux Machine:
`gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lgdal -lm`, but I also wanted to create an executable to run the same program on windows. I found the steps found in the following post: https://lazyadminblog.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-build-gdal-from-source-for.html
Steps:

- Download from http://www.gdal.org the source package for GDAL
- Extract the .zip file and generate a _vcxproj.bat script in Powershell with parameters by typing .\generage_vcxproj.bat 14.0 64 gdal_vs2015
- Execute the file created "gdal_vs2015.vcxproj"
- Build in Visual Studio by typing CTRL + SHIFT + B
- Create a VS Code Studio Project and open the properties and add the following directories in the "Include Directories" and "Library Directories" the following paths: $C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4 $C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4\gcore $C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4\apps $C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4\port $C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4\ogr
- Add in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies the following path: "C:\Users\user_name\gdal-3.0.4\gdal_i.lib"
- Create executable of the C Code

The process ended creating a .exe file, which I understand it as being the executable of the program for a Windows Platform. However when I execute the program I got an Error along this lines: `System error: The program can't start because MSVCP140D.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem`. I did reinstall gdal, but it did not solved the problem. Did anyone confronted this problem, and found a solution to it?